# How To Use NodeJS Module await?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have the following code that uses the await module which technically work (I **think**).

```
var await = require('await')
var sleep = require('sleep')

var things = await('one', 'two');

function getData(key){      
  console.log("IN FUNCTION " + key);
  sleep.sleep(5);
  var data = "got data for " + key;
  things.keep(key, data);
  console.log("DONE WIH FUNCTION " + key);
}


console.log("start");
getData('one');
getData('two');
console.log('end');

things.then(function(got){
  console.log(got.one);
  console.log(got.two); 
} 
);
```

The output is:

```
start
IN FUNCTION one
DONE WIH FUNCTION one
IN FUNCTION two
DONE WIH FUNCTION two
end
got data for one
got data for two
```

Everything seems to get passed along as it should fulfilling promises. However, It looks like it is executing synchronously not asynchronously. I would have expected to see:

```
start
IN FUNCTION one
IN FUNCTION two
DONE WIH FUNCTION one
DONE WIH FUNCTION two
end
got data for one
got data for two
```

It also takes about 10 seconds which it should only take barley over 5 seconds.

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep. It says `These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!`

Answer (score 1):

sleep is blocking, and not returning control to the event loop, so your code just sleeps right where it says sleep.

If you convert it to async, with `setTimeout` like this:

```
function getData(key){      
  console.log("IN FUNCTION " + key);
  setTimeout(function() {
    var data = "got data for " + key;
    things.keep(key, data);
    console.log("DONE WIH FUNCTION " + key);
  }, 5000);
}
```

I get this output:

```
start
IN FUNCTION one
IN FUNCTION two
end
DONE WIH FUNCTION one
got data for one
got data for two
DONE WIH FUNCTION two
```

Which looks correct to me.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  I was using sleep to simulate something that  took a few seconds to do.  How can I make a function asynchronous without having the setTimoutout?  Or are functions naturally  asynchronous unless they call a blocking method?

Comment: Javascript is synchronous. But most libraries written in C, like IO and other functions are asynchronous. What kind of functions do you want to make async?

Comment: I want to do several REST calls   then collect all the results and process the data.  Is there a way to tell if a function is blocking or non-blocking?  And is there a way to make your own non-blocking  asynchronous function?

Comment: To make it yourself you have to write it in C, or use functions that are async. async functions in JS are either using the callback or the Promise pattern, so they are easy to spot. `request` library for instance is async, so that should be easily achievable.